# Is it possible to use Azure Service Bus with Azure AD (not ADFS) for exposing AX 2012 services?

Tags: azureservicebus, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I have been tasked with developing an integration to an external system and I believe Azure Service Bus is the way I'm supposed to go. If not, I'm open to suggestions. I need to push/pull customers/vendors, sales/purch orders, then certain action events (posting picking lists, etc).

I was thinking AIF and maybe some custom AX services if I can't find an existing one.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/service-integration-architecture-with-windows-azure-service-bus-relay it needs Azure Directory Federation Services (ADFS) but is that outdated?

The mobile connector documentation used to say ADFS, but they changed it to allow Azure Active Directory (AAD).

What's the best way to safely expose the various services in AX to an external system? We have AAD.

Comment: Take a look at [How to integrate Dynamics AX 2012 with Azure and Power Platform](https://devblog.sertanyaman.com/2021/01/11/how-to-integrate-dynamics-ax-2012-with-azure-and-power-platform/), using an Azure Relay Service seems to be another option to safey expose an AX service.

Comment: @FH-Inway I've been evaluating this option since you pointed me at it, and it's perfect! If you make your comment an actual reply I can mark it solved. I think that link will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to integrate Dynamics AX 2012 with Azure and Power Platform](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123190628/https://devblog.sertanyaman.com/2021/01/11/how-to-integrate-dynamics-ax-2012-with-azure-and-power-platform/) describes several options to integrate and expose AX 2012 services with Azure.

One of them is how to use an [Azure Relay Service](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101130417/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-what-is-it) to safely expose a service running on an on premise system to external clients.

As the article mentions, to use that option, you need to create a custom ASP.NET Core REST proxy service for your AIF endpoints. It also points to a GitHub repository where a sample for such a proxy service can be found: https://github.com/sertanyaman/ax2012-aif-aspnetcore-proxyservice-sample