# Use Dynamics AX 2009 Business Connector .NET Framework 3.5 inside .NET Core solution

Tags: .net-core, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

We are working on a `.NET Core` solution where the request comes in to do some communications with `Dynamics AX 2009`.

In AX we have some static methods that we need to call from within our solution. In other `.NET Framework` solutions we used the Business Connector that gets installed with AX. This was always working fine but now in the `.NET Core` solution we got exception during Autofac resolving:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 
An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void 
.ctor(Core.Configuration.AppConfig, Core.Logging.ILogger)' on type
'AxConnectionProvider'. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
'Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Which is correct because the Business Connector is not supported in `.NET Core`.

But how can we solve this issue in order to work with AX 2009 and call static methods from within our `.NET Core` solution?

We have a `.NET Standard` library where we included all AX code and where we included the Business Connector dll as a reference.

Comment: Can you just use your `.NET Standard` library as a proxy and call it from your `.NET Core` solution? Have you proven your standard library works correctly?

Comment: What I did is create a class inside this class library which calls the Business Connector and does all kinds of operations. But then in Autofac in my ASP.NET Core website I need to register this proxy class to be used in other services and there I got the exception. The Business connector is in the output folder. Current solution I did was to create a separated internal ASP.NET WebAPI in .NET Framework which contains all the Business Connector related operations. Then I call this using a Typed HttpClient from within my .NET Core project.

Comment: See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779152/is-it-possible-to-use-azure-service-bus-with-azure-ad-not-adfs-for-exposing-ax. You could ignore the AzureRelay part unless you wanted to use it. I believe AX2009 has WCF services, you could just use them as connected services with your ASP.NET Core application and be done. You could skip the BC all together.