# AX 2009 integration in an azure app service

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am looking into integrating our AX 2009 with an Azure app service. The app service need to create and update employees in the AX HRM.

I can see that my options are either business connector or AIF.
I am completely new to everything-AX, and have no experience with either integrations.

Any advice as to which service I should use for integration with an app service? Will I hit any wall with either service when the integration will be used in the cloud?
It seems to me that AIF should be the way to go, as the business connector requires knowledge of which specific tables to create records in.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779152/is-it-possible-to-use-azure-service-bus-with-azure-ad-not-adfs-for-exposing-ax

Comment: AIF is most likely the way to go for your application and the answer @FH-Inway posted is definitely a good start.

Comment: @FH-Inway Thank you for the link - it looks very promising! I'll have a good look-through :)

AlexKwitny: Thanks, good to know I'm heading in the right direction